# Class with both template and non-template constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, c++11, constructor

### I. Problem description:

Class `Derived` is a child of class `Base`. You can not modify class `Base`. Define constructors and assignement operators for `Derived` so that it could be constructed both from instances of:

- `Base`<sup>1</sup>
- `Derived`<sup>1</sup>
- `N` non-polymorphic and not related types `Foo1`, ... , `FooN`<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Construction from both `Base` and `Derived` is done using `Base` copy constructor.

<sup>2</sup> Construction from all of `Foo1`, ... , `FooN` is done by a generic algorithm.

### II. Possible solutions:

#### 1. Brute force:

`N+1` separate constructors + `N+1` separate assignment operators. Absolutely not elegant. Tons of useless code: `N+1` methods declarations in header + `N+1` methods implementations in source. Power of templates not used.

#### 2. Template constructor with type restriction

Declare and define regular copy-constructor

```
Derived::Derived ( const Base& object_reference ) { ... }
```

Declare template constructor:

```
template<typename type>
Derived::Derived ( const type& object_reference );
```

Implement for each of `Foo0`, ... , `FooN`

```
template<>
Derived::Derived<Foo0> ( const Foo0& object_reference ) { ... }

...

template<>
Derived::Derived<Foo9> ( const Foo9& object_reference ) { ... }
```

As a result the header will contain only two constructors and only two assignment operators. But we will have to implement `N+1` methods in the source. I believe there is a better solution anyway.

### III. What will not work:

#### 1. Separating `Base` and `Derived` from others using `dynamic_cast`

```
template<typename type>
Derived::Derived ( const type& object_reference )
{

    //  This line will not compile since `Foo0`, ... , `FooN` are non-polymorthic
    Base* base_ptr = dynamic_cast <Base*> (&object_reference);

    if ( base_ptr != nullptr )
    {

        //  Construct from `Base`
        return;

    }

    //  Construct from `Foo0`, ... , `FooN`

}
```

#### 2. Separating `Base` and `Derived` from others using `typeid`

```
template<typename type>
Derived::Derived ( const type& object_reference )
{

    if
    (
        typeid(typename) == typeid(Foo0)
            ||
            ...
            ||
        typeid(typename) == typeid(FooN)
    }
    {

        //  Construct from `Foo0`, ... , `FooN`
        return;

    }

    else
    {

        //  Construct from `Base`

        //  Here we should call `Base` members which `Foo0`, ... , `FooN` don't have
        //  so the following line will not compile
        //  object_reference.some_method();
        //  And we need to cast "&object_reference" to "Base*" what is not possible
        //  because `Foo0`, ... , `FooN` are not polimorthic

    }

}
```

### IV. The question:

Is there any efficient way, which is not described in section II, to solve the problem?

Comment: Do `Foo0..FooN` have something in common?

Comment: @Rapptz One generic algorithm constructs from any of them.

Comment: "Define constructors and assignement operators for Derived so that it could be constructed" What do assignment ops have to do with construction?

Comment: Sounds like a job for delegating ctors "Construction from both Base and Derived is done using Base copy constructor." and a template ctor with SFINAE for the `Foo` restrictions.

Comment: what kind of class is this? does it have `N` members of types `Foo1` to `FooN`? or is this just an exercise?

Comment: @TemplateRex it's not an exercise. It's a real world example. `Base` is `socket_address`, `Derived` is `posix_socket_address` and `Foo1` - `FooN` are `sockaddr_storage`, `sockaddr`, `sockaddr_in`, `sockaddr_in6`, `sockaddr_un`, ...

Comment: @Rapptz nothing common but `One generic algorithm constructs from any of them`

Comment: I think critical information is missing here, namely what the construction from `Foo0..FooN` would do. If every type leads to an own action that cannot be generalized, there *is no point in using templates*. Actually, what you call brute force would be the correct solution, because it defines exactly with which types the constructor will work. Templates only make sense if the construction can be generalized for all or some of `Foo0..FooN`.

Comment: Don't forget ``explicit``.

Comment: @flyx I've explicitly stated that construction from `Foo0..FooN` is done by the same generic algorithm. In fact it's just `memcpy` the whole object. So it's reasonable to make it template.

Comment: @Kolyunya: Why do you need to specialize the template constructor in II.2 then?

Comment: @flyx because `Foo0...FooN` do not have a base? Don't you mean to pass each of `Foo0...FooN` by a `void*` + `size_t`

Comment: @Kolyunya `2. Separating Base and Derived from others using typeid` why do you need `typeid`? Make two ctors from `Base` and `Derived` (non-template) and make template one for `Foo` classes.

Comment: @ruslo that is what I was actually looking for. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `typeid` here:

```
2. Separating `Base` and `Derived` from others using `typeid`
```

Just make two non-template ctors and one template ctor for Foo classes:

```
class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived(const Derived&);
  Derived(const Base&);

  template<class Foo>
  Derived(const Foo&);
};
```

Comment: If there is a chance to do construction from Foo 1 to Foo n within one template there seems to be no reason to not separate the things in foo base and foo derived ( 0 .. n ). If this answer is the correct solution, I could not really understand the question from op.

Answer (score 1):

From the information in your comments, there actually is a commonality between `Foo1` and `FooN`, namely they are all encodings of a socket address. So make a `to_string()` serialization in the various `FooAny` classes,

```
class FooAny // Any runs from 1 to N
{
public:
    std::string to_string() const { /* FooAny specific */ }
private:
    // bla
};
```

and then use a single template constructor in `Derived` that delegate to a regular construtor taking a `std::string` argument

```
class Derived
{
    explicit Derived(std::string const& s): /* convert data members from string */ {}

    template<class Foo>
    explicit Derived(Foo const& f): Derived(f.to_string()) {} // delegating constructor
};
```

Comment: Alternative one could implement it using a to_string trait, and you wouldn't have to add this member, if you didn't like to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two cents. ([Code](http://ideone.com/uXHFS4) on Ideone.com)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace so
{
struct _base_ {};

struct _foo1_{};
struct _foo2_{};
struct _foo3_{};

class _derived_: public _base_
{
 public:
  _derived_() = default;

  _derived_(_derived_ const & _obj)
      : _base_(_obj)
  {
   std::cout << "Constructed from _derived_" << std::endl;
  }

  _derived_(_base_ const & _obj)
      : _base_(_obj)
  {
   std::cout << "Constructed from _base_" << std::endl;
  }

  template <typename _t_, typename = typename std::enable_if<
     std::is_same<_t_, _foo1_>::value || std::is_same<_t_, _foo2_>::value || 
     std::is_same<_t_, _foo3_>::value>::type>
  _derived_(_t_ const &)
      : _base_()
  {
   std::cout << "Constructed from _fooN_ using generic algorithm" << std::endl;
  }

  ~_derived_() noexcept (true) = default;
};
} //namespace so


int main()
{
 so::_base_ b_{};
 so::_derived_ d_{};
 so::_foo1_ f1_{};
 so::_foo2_ f2_{};
 so::_foo3_ f3_{};

 so::_derived_ db_{b_};
 so::_derived_ dd_{d_};
 so::_derived_ df1_{f1_};
 so::_derived_ df2_{f2_};
 so::_derived_ df3_{f3_};

 return (0);
}
```